# Format timestamp in AngularJS to a custom requirement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a string of numbers returned from a new post that is timestamped the moment its submitted in the format `new Date().getTime()`. I wish to put a duration timestamp like `(new Date().getTime() of submitted post - current date time)` or essentially the date time elapsed from when the post was submitted.

The subtraction will return as mins **or** hours **or** days ago if < a month duration (but definition of a month varies, some Feb has 28 days?). Not sure if theres global timezone adjustments. If its > a month, to show it as `month (Jan, Mar, Dec etc)` and the `year 2014` for example without any duration involved.

I heard of moment.JS but not sure if theres such a customization for above. How should I approach the converting? Appreciate if theres a sample code(s) to reference to.

Many thanks!

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` returns a single number, a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1). The "duration timestamp" will be a similar value that represents a number of milliseconds. This can't be "converted to months", it's just a number of milliseconds that can be trivially converted to days, hours, minutes and seconds. It can be converted to months, years if some epoch is provided.

Comment: @RobG when i used new Date().toUTCString(), it gave the month and year as well. THats why I though the string had month and year in it. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a string of numbers returned from new Date().getTime()

That will be a single number that represents the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (the ECMAScript epoch) and the UTC time that the code is executed.

> and saved as that in the back end. I wish to put a duration timestamp like (new Date().getTime() - now()).

If `now()` is shorthand for `Date.now()` then the result of that expression will be zero (0), since both expressions will represent the same instant in time.

> However I want filter to show it as mins, hours, days ago

It's trivial to convert a value in milliseconds to values for days, hours, minutes, seconds.

> if its less than a month (but definition of a month varies, Feb sometimes has 28 days?) Im not sure if the timestamp string accounts for global timezone adjustments.

The time value at the heart of a Date object is UTC milliseconds since the epoch. Date objects also have an offset that is determined from system settings and is used to calculate local time values. There are UTC methods to get UTC values and non–UTC methods to get local values.

> If its more than a month, to show it as month (Jan, Mar, Dec etc) and the year 2014 for example without any duration involved.

The result of subtracting two time values is a scalar number, it has no concept of months or years, it simply represents a duration, not a moment. So converting a number to "months" only makes sense if there is a specific starting point (epoch) and direction.

E.g.

1 Jan + 31 days -> 1 Feb so one month, but 1 Jun + 31 days -> 2 Jul so 1 month and 1 day.

1 Jan - 31 days -> 1 Dec so one month, and 1 June - 31 days -> 1 May so 1 month.

> I heard of moment JS but not sure if theres such a customization for duration

I don't know much about moment.js, only that I've never found a need for it.

> How should I approach the converting?

Start by clarifying your requirements. Perhaps you want to represent a duration as say months, days, hours, etc. from a particular point in time (such as now, or 1 June 2014, or whatever)?

Some of the above is trivial, some is quite difficult and depends on administrative rules, e.g. is 29 Feb 2012 + 1 year 28 Feb 2013 or 1 Mar 2013?

#### Edit

The sample code below is a fairly robust way of determining the years, months and days between two dates. It also does hours:minutes:seconds where the time difference is less than 1 day (i.e. 8.64e7 millliseconds).

It may look like a lot of code, the vast bulk is in doing the years, months, days part.

```
/**
 * Return the number of days in the month for the given year.
 * Month is calendar month (Jan=1, Feb=2, etc.).
 * @param {number} [month]
 * @param {number} [year]
 * @returns {number}
 * Default is current month, current year
*/
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(12,0,0,0);
  if (typeof month == 'undefined') month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  if (typeof year  == 'undefined') year  = d.getFullYear();
  d.setFullYear(year, month, 0);
  return d.getDate();
}

/**
 * Add years to a given Date, modifies the Date.
 * If adding years to 29 Feb rolls over to March 1,
 * then the date is set to 28 Feb.
 * @param {Date} date - Date to add years to
 * @param {number} years - Number of years to add
 * @returns {Date} Modified original date object
*/
function addYears(date, years) {
  var m = date.getMonth();
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + years);

  // Deal with leap year: if 29 Feb -> 1 Mar set back to 28 Feb
  if (date.getMonth() != m) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}

/**
 * Add months to a given Date, modifies the Date.
 * If adding months causes the date to roll over an extra month,
 * the date is set to last day of previous month.
 *
 * e.g. 31 May + 1 month -> 30 June, not 1 July
 *      31 Jan + 1 month -> 28 Feb or 29 Feb if leap year
 * @param {Date} date - Date to add months to
 * @param {number} months - Number of months to add
 * @returns {Date} Modified original
*/
function addMonths(date, months) {
    var n = date.getDate();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);

    if (date.getDate() != n) {
        date.setDate(0);
    }
    return date;
}

/**
 * Add days to a given Date, modifies the Date.
 * @param {Date} date - Date to add days to
 * @param {number} days - Number of days to add
 * @returns {Date} Modified original
*/
function addDays(date, days) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

/**
 * Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss
 * @param {number|string} secs
 * @returns {number}
*/
function secondsToHMS(secs) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
  var sign = secs < 0? '-':'';
  secs = Math.abs(secs);
  return sign + z(secs/3600 |0) + ':' + z((secs%3600) / 60 |0) + ':' + z(secs%60);
}

/**
 * Get the time between two dates as years, months and days.
 * For startDate of 29 Feb, whole year is 28 Feb in following year or
 * 29 Feb if endDate is a leap year. Some systems use 1 Mar.
 * @param {Date} startDate
 * @param {Date} [endDate]
 * @returns {string} 'y years, m moths and d days'
 * If endDate not provided, current date is used.
 * endDate must be after startDate.
*/
function getAge(startDate, endDate) {

    // Return undefined if start date is after end date
    if (startDate > endDate) return;

    var d, d0, d1, years, months, days;
    var startMonth = startDate.getMonth();

    d1 = endDate? new Date(+endDate) : new Date();
    d1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    d = new Date(+startDate);
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    d0 = new Date(+d);

    years = d1.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear();
    addYears(d, years);

    if (d > d1) {
        --years;
        d = new Date(+d0);
        addYears(d, years);
    }

    months = d1.getMonth() - d.getMonth();

    // Deal with -ve month difference
    if (months < 0) {
        months += 12;

    // Deal with months the same and difference < 1 year
    } else if (months == 0 && d.getFullYear() != d1.getFullYear()) {
        months = 11;
    }

    addMonths(d, months);

    if (d > d1) {
        --months;
        d = new Date(+d0);
        addYears(d, years);
        addMonths(d, months);
    }

    days = d1.getDate() - d.getDate();

    if (days < 0 ) {
        days += getDaysInMonth(d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear());

    } else if (days == 0 && d1.getMonth() != d.getMonth()) {
        days = getDaysInMonth(d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()) - 1;
    }

    // Helper to make words plural if num != 1
    function s(num, word) {return word + (num == 1? '' : 's')}

    return years  + s(years,  ' year' ) + ', ' +
           months + s(months, ' month') + ', ' +
           days   + s(days,   ' day'  );
}


// Basic function to parse an ISO 8601 format string as a
// local time. Any timezone is ignored.
// Honours 2 digit years, so 14 is not 1914.
function parseString(s) {
  var d = new Date();
  b = s.split(/\D+/);
  d.setFullYear(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2]);
  d.setHours(b[3] || 0, b[4] || 0, b[5]);
  return d;
}


function showDuration() {
  var el = document.getElementById('d0');
  var now = new Date();

  // Convert date string to a Date object
  var then = parseString(document.getElementById('i0').value);

  // If not a valid date, do nothing
  if (!then) return;

  // If difference greater than 1 day, show years, months, etc.
  // Otherwise, show h:m:s
  el.innerHTML = ((now - then) > 8.64e7? getAge(then, now) :
                  secondsToHMS(Math.abs(then - now)/1000 | 0)) + ' ago.';
}
```

Some markup:

```
<input id="i0" value="2014-06-23T20:28:09">
<button onclick="showDuration()">Show duration</button>
<br>
<div id="d0"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have updated my question accordingly. Basically duration between current date/time versus date/time when post is submitted. So if difference is less than a month, to display it as either mins, hours, days. If > month then display as MMM YYYY. And since both are miliseconds from 1970 date, I supposed that the difference between the 2 date times will be duration versus the submitted date time.

Comment: Calculating time differences as years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds is not trivial (it's actually quite hard). There are many, many simple solutions but they all have serious flaws that may not be immediately apparent. This is why most "time ago" functions just say things like "about 1 year ago" or "about 2 months ago", the "about" part means they don't have to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use moment.js, it handles all of this.  You can use [fromnow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
```

If you don't like what it gives you, it's [customizable](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/):

```
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d');  // 26
```

also see [calendar](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/), which is customizable.

or, you can use the [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

a.diff(b, 'days') // 1

finally, you could also use [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

```
moment.duration(2, 'weeks');
```

For formatting how it is displayed, you can use [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
```

and it also supports time zones and utc, and localization.

Comment: I think fromNow() is good enough. What if for duration longer than 30 days, which i hope to display as MMM YYYY format (i.e no longer the difference)? Reason being I need to lower the amount of filter watches on cycles. How do I customize the Thresholds? The docs show it but no mention if its in html or js and how it should be done? like does it require a directive or filter?

Comment: you use moment js directly in your controllers or directives, it is done in javascript.  same for customizing the thresholds.  to change the format, use an if statement, something like - if < 1 month, moment.fromNow() else moment.format('MMM YYYY').  i'll try to put together a plunkr later tonight.

Comment: Thanks @edamon, appreciate your help. I cant seem to get moment working in the angularjs project. Error says module not found.  I included src for moment.js in (index.html) as well as included as dependencies in global variable (app.js).

Comment: Or am I supposed to use angular-moment.js?

Comment: you can use that, but I don't think it's going to do what you want.  all it does is wrap moment in an angular directive.  I've used it before in a really data intensive application, and we had to rip it out because it was not performant.  I think you'll neeed that if statement.  module not found is an angular error, can you post your code and error?

Comment: shows this `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'moment' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` and this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. My codes are adding as script `<script src="bower_components/moment.js"></script>` and as dependencies `var app = angular.module('Prototype', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'moment']);`

Comment: take it out of angular.module as a dependency, or create a module for it like the one that exists for ionic or firebase.  You're attempting to load a module 'moment', which you did not create.  if you're adding it via script tag, it's available on the global scope.  so you can just use.  Or better, you can inject it as a constant or value into your main app.js... "app.constant('moment', moment);"  now you can inject it into any angular controller or service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67283/discussion-between-thinkerer-and-edamon).